# Is a partition a relation?

Tags: greenplum

Is a partition a relation in its own right, or is a partitioned table a single relation? Specifically, do we need to increase max_fsm_relations when we split tables up into loads of partitions?

Comment: I don't know for sure Greenplum handles this like PostgreSQL did at the time, but if yes, then yes :)  A partition has its entry in `pg_classes`, for example, as a regular table.

Answer (score 0):

When you Partition a table, physical tables are created and when you query table with where predicates on partition only partition tables queried, you can also query a particular partition.

Comment: Yes, I know each partition is a separate table, the question is: is it a separate relation?